# SQL Server 2014: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the following error while trying to execute the query shown in SQL Server 2014. I have data customers chat data and I want to replace the customers with "Customer" and Agent name with "Agent"

> Error :- Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Data format:

```
11:35:41 Daniella Sichtman : I don't mind. It's ok 
11:35:55 Daniella Sichtman : Did you understand my problem? 
11:36:09 Madan : Yes, I got your issue. 
11:36:20 Madan : Please stay connected while I check what best I can do for you. 
11:37:01 Daniella Sichtman : OK. If I may suggest. Mail the hotel that we need 2 nights. I have their contact information if you need that. 
11:37:21 Daniella Sichtman : The room are availible they told us 
11:37:41 Daniella Sichtman : Just need an ok 
11:37:43 Madan : Have you visited the hotel reception to extend your stay ? 
11:38:01 Daniella Sichtman : Yes. They told us you need to give the ok 
11:39:14 Madan : Nico, I would like to Inform you that we have already authorized to the hotel to extend the stay for our guests. 
11:39:46 Daniella Sichtman : They don't know about that or did you told them this morning?
```

SQL Code:-

```
SELECT REPLACE(Transcript,
               SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(transcript, CHARINDEX(' ', transcript) + 1, (((LEN(transcript)) - CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(transcript))) - CHARINDEX(' ', transcript))),
                         1,
                         CASE
                              WHEN CHARINDEX(':', SUBSTRING(transcript, CHARINDEX(' ', transcript) + 1, (((LEN(transcript)) - CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(transcript))) - CHARINDEX(' ', transcript)))) = 0 THEN LEN(Transcript)
                              ELSE CHARINDEX(':', SUBSTRING(transcript, CHARINDEX(' ', transcript) + 1, (((LEN(transcript)) - CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(transcript))) - CHARINDEX(' ', transcript)))) - 2
                         END),
               'Customer')
FROM [easyJet_Staging].[dbo].[KANA_Chat_Transcript_StageAll]
WHERE Transcript IS NOT NULL
  AND Transcript <> '';
```

Note: I have seen many post but didn't get the desired output. I would request to all of you, could you help me.

Expected output:-

```
XX:XX:XX Agent : I do understand what you are saying but I am afraid, but any instrument larger than XXcm x XXXcm x XXcm like a double bass or harp can’t be taken on board the aircraft as cabin baggage. 
XX:XX:XX Customer : Hello, it's a GUITAR. it is just X cm bigger, the case is Xcm thicker. 
XX:XX:XX Customer : it's a soft case that can be pushed to fit your dimensions 
XX:XX:XX Agent : I do understand what you are saying but even it is X cm then also they will ask you to put it on hold and we do understand that you are worried if it gets damaged but there won't be any case and you can get the fragile tag from the Airport so that it will be taken care. 
XX:XX:XX Customer : What if I take it on board (priority boarding) and it fits within their dimensions exactly and can go in an overhead locker?
```

Comment: You forgot to include your SQL! We can't help you if we don't know what caused the error.

Comment: How is one supposed to differentiate agents from customers?

Comment: Why not `REPLACE(column_name, 'customers name', 'Customer')` (and the same for agent)?

Comment: You may want to review the official Microsoft documentation to figure out why your syntax is wrong: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I have added my code Please check

Comment: That code, with that data, doesn't generate the error your describe. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2c7d10bd28b50ecd6f0d5d7b50c3546d).

Comment: Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Presumably with different code and / or different data?

Answer (score 0):

SUBSTRING spec indicates that it will accept any int for the the second argument, but must have a positive int for the third. So the problem is probably in the third parameter. ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 )

Sounds like you have records in your data that don't fit what you are expecting: Try the query to identify them. It looks for any records where the third parameter of the substring is zero or negative.

Because of the way SQL works, sometimes functions in the select will be applied to records before they are filtered out using the where clause. It is safest to make sure your select will work on all records, even the ones that will be filtered out in the where clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    [easyJet_Staging].[dbo].[KANA_Chat_Transcript_StageAll]
WHERE (((LEN(transcript)) - CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(transcript))) - CHARINDEX(' ', transcript)) <= 0
    OR CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX(':', SUBSTRING(transcript, CHARINDEX(' ', transcript) + 1, (((LEN(transcript)) - CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(transcript))) - CHARINDEX(' ', transcript)))) = 0 THEN LEN(Transcript)
        ELSE CHARINDEX(':', SUBSTRING(transcript, CHARINDEX(' ', transcript) + 1, (((LEN(transcript)) - CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(transcript))) - CHARINDEX(' ', transcript)))) - 2
    END <=0
```